# >> bitwise operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to create a simple utility for myself to be able to convert values from rgb to hex, and vice versa. It works for the most part, except for one flaw.

If I enter a hex value like `'007aff'`, `'00'` gets trimmed and the result is `'7aff'`. The r/g/b/ still gets the correct value, but I don't want the zeroes trimmed from the hexadecimal value. Am I doing something incorrectly?

```
// for anyone unfamiliar with angular
// $watch runs when the variable in quotes changes in value
// the rest is basic javascript
```

AngularJS:

```
  $scope.$watch('hex', function() {

    var rgb = parseInt($scope.hex, 16);

    $scope.r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $scope.g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $scope.b = rgb & 0xFF;

    $scope.rgb = 'rgb(' + $scope.r + ',' + $scope.g + ',' + $scope.b + ');';

  });

  $scope.$watch('r+g+b', function() {

    $scope.rgb = 'rgb(' + $scope.r + ',' + $scope.g + ',' + $scope.b + ');';
    $scope.hex = parseInt($scope.r << 16 | $scope.g << 8 | $scope.b).toString(16);
  });
```

[Here is a sample Plunker:](http://embed.plnkr.co/EI3IUdgeTs3aXhrWmhGa/preview)

Answer (score 1):

The `00` aren't directly *trimmed*. When your convert the rgb *number* to a string, you don't format it with leading zeros.

Try this to format with leading zeros:

```
var value = parseInt($scope.r << 16 | $scope.g << 8 | $scope.b);
$scope.hex = ('000000' + value.toString(16)).slice(-6);
```

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
$scope.hex = parseInt($scope.r << 16 | $scope.g << 8 | $scope.b).toString(16);
```

add the following lines:

```
var len = $scope.hex.length;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 6 - len ; i++ ) {
  $scope.hex = '0' + $scope.hex;
}
```